# Volley PATCH is not working in Pre-lollipop deives

Tags: android, android-volley, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

volley + gson PATCH is not working in pre-lollipo [Kitkat] devices.
Here is the code.....

```
GsonRequestJson gsonRequestJson = new GsonRequestJson(Request.Method.PATCH,url, WishlistItems.class, headers, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<WishlistItems>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onResponse(WishlistItems response) {
                                           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Successfully removed from wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                           hEart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_heartempty);
                                           // dialog.dismiss();

                                       Gson gson = new Gson();
                                       String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(response)));
                                       MainActivity.tinyDB.putString(Constants.MY_SHARED_PREF_MARKEDITEMS, jsonFavorites);

                                   }
                               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                       Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                               .show();
                                       Log.d("Error---", "-----" + error.toString());
                                   }
                               });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

Change Request.Method.PATCH to Request.Method.POST, and then change the header type to PUT as below.

```
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            headers.put("Authorization", "JWT " + Constants.load(mContext,Constants.MY_SHARED_PREF_TOKEN));
                            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            headers.put("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT");
```

PS: This is just a hack but not the actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `POST` while sending request and override `X-HTTP-Method-Override` to PATCH

```
headers.put("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
```

Comment: your server should support Method override to let this work